# Pass parameters while starting Android Activity from Unity 3D

Tags: android, android-activity, unity-game-engine

I managed to start an external Android Activity from within Unity 3D

Here's my code

```
public void StartPackage()
{
    AndroidJavaClass activityClass;
    AndroidJavaObject activity, packageManager;
    AndroidJavaObject launch;

    string package = "com.example.unitysender";

    activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    activity = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    packageManager = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
    launch = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", package);
    activity.Call("startActivity", launch);
}
```

And here's my Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("UnityToAndroid");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        finish();
    }    
}
```

As you can see, *StartPackage* from Unity starts an Android Activity in a 3rd part application, and that Activity sends a broadcast.
I was wondering, is there any way I can pass some parameters while doing so?
Obviously, right now there's no code in both of them to send/receive any data, but I need my activity to receive an integer to pass inside the broadcast, so I'm not forced to call this method *x* times.

Comment: Where is the Java function you want to pass int to? It would be good to post what it looks like.

Comment: Done, have a look, thanks!